# How to detect Formula Expressions exposing vulnerable information like session id?

Tags: formula, security, security-scanner

There is a snippet from the [Salesforce Security Guide (Version 58.0)](https://blog.bessereau.eu/assets/pdfs/salesforce_security_impl_guide.pdf)

**Formula Tag** heading explaining why it is a security vulnerability :

```
The general syntax of these tags is:{!FUNCTION()} or {!$OBJECT.ATTRIBUTE}. For example, if a developer wanted to include
a user's session ID in a link, they can create the link by using this syntax.

<a
href="http://partner.domain.com/integration/?sid={!$Api.Session_ID}&server={!$Api.Partner_Server_URL_130}">
Go to portal</a>

And it renders like this output.

<a
href="http://partner.domain.com/integration/?sid=4f0900D30000000Jsbi%21AQoAQNYaPnVyd_6hNdIxXhzQTMaa
SlYiOfRzpM18huTGN3jC0O1FIkbuQRwPc9OQJeMRm4h2UYXRnmZ5wZufIrvd9DtC_ilA&server=https://yourInstance.salesforce.com
/services/Soap/u/13.0/4f0900D30000000Jsbi">Go to portal</a>
```

So I tried creating a custom formula to expose my org's session ID.

Then I tried running these tools to detect these formula expression but no cigar :

1. [Salesforce Optimizer](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.optimizer_kick_off.htm&language=en_US&type=5)
2. [Security Health Check](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_health_check.htm&language=en_US&type=5)
3. Salesforce Code Analyzer (but this scans for Code not metadata)

Any ideas how I can detect this so called vulnerability?

Comment: you could write some custom rules for PMD and make it a part of your pieline, ....

Comment: That is if you put that formula into Apex/VF/Aura/LWC. Can PMD detect just the formula field itself if not being used anywhere on Apex/VF/Aura/LWC?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a vulnerability, simply an example of how formulas can be used. Later in the paragraph, they state that if you allow editable, unescaped values into your code, you can introduce vulnerabilities. For example, $Request should always be appropriately escaped in order to avoid specially crafted links from stealing session data or any other data.

> It can be dangerous if the formula expression references nonsystem data that’s hostile or editable and the expression isn’t wrapped in a function to escape the output during rendering.

Note that the [Salesforce Code Analyzer](https://forcedotcom.github.io/sfdx-scanner/) will report proper XSS vulnerabilities. You didn't get any vulnerability warnings because there aren't any. Try the following, which should trigger a warning:

```
<script>
let age = {!$Request.age}
</script>
```